# Okta login is working in desktop browsers but not working in Ipad

Tags: angular, okta

I have the below issue

1. I have integrated Okta in my angular application its working fine in desktop browsers.
2. I tried to login to the application in ipad 12.9 2021 (in both safari and chrome browsers), login is not working and the same login page is reloaded again
3. okta auth call is not giving any reponse in ipad. Please find below screenshot for the same
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUnW4.png
4. I am not getting any errors in console as well